# Parse failure when trying to load json file to elasticsearch

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to load a json file in elasticsearch. I am first creating the index using XPUT as follows-

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/project5' -d @med.json
```

I am the trying to load the data from the json file using the following command-

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/project5/_search' -d @med.json '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":100}'
```

But it is giving me this error-

```
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query],all shards failed; shardFailures {[B3acaOD7SauK8bRWlX24vQ][project5][4]: SearchParseException[[project5][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{    \"media_type\": \"game\",    \"title\": \"Final Fantasy VI\",    \"year\": \"1994\"}]]];
nested: SearchParseException[[project5][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [media_type]]]; }{[B3acaOD7SauK8bRWlX24vQ][project5][1]: SearchParseException[[project5][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{    \"media_type\": \"game\",    \"title\": \"Final Fantasy VI\",    \"year\": \"1994\"}]]];
nested: SearchParseException[[project5][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [media_type]]]; }{[B3acaOD7SauK8bRWlX24vQ][project5][0]: SearchParseException[[project5][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{    \"media_type\": \"game\",    \"title\": \"Final Fantasy VI\",    \"year\": \"1994\"}]]]; curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos 10
nested: SearchParseException[[project5][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [media_type]]]; }{[B3acaOD7SauK8bRWlX24vQ][project5][3]: SearchParseException[[project5][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{    \"media_type\": \"game\",    \"title\": \"Final Fantasy VI\",    \"year\": \"1994\"}]]]; 
nested: SearchParseException[[project5][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [media_type]]]; }{[B3acaOD7SauK8bRWlX24vQ][project5][2]: SearchParseException[[project5][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{    \"media_type\": \"game\",    \"title\": \"Final Fantasy VI\",    \"year\": \"1994\"}]]];
nested: SearchParseException[[project5][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [media_type]]]; }]","status":400}
```

My json file is as follows-

```
{
"media_type":"game",
"title":"Final Fantasy VI",
"year":"1994"
},
{
"media_type":"book",
"title":"Harry Potter",
"year":"2010"
},
{
"media_type":"music",
"title":"Surfing With The Alien",
"year":"1987"
}
```

Can you please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@med.json` from your query. Your query should be as under:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/project5/_search' -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":100}'
```

See [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) for example.

Comment: I tried this.It gives the following output -                                                            {"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}} But it is not displaying the data in the file.

Comment: The response is correct. Actually the way you are indexing documents is incorrect. You need to use bulk API for indexing multiple documents at the same time. Read more at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html